# Athena (Presto) Count: check for update, if updated count update , otherwise count insert row

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

In very simple terms, for Athena (Presto Sql) i need to return a count of unique Names. If the row has an update, I only want to count the Name of the updated row, and not the insert row. If there is no update, just count Name from the insert row normally.
I believe things should only update once.

```
ID    NAME    ROW_TYPE   TIME
1     A        Insert    1:00
1     A        Update    1:05
2     B        Insert    1:06
3     C        Insert    1:07
```

I was thinking maybe I can do a ROLL UP and just count normally ? (Not sure if a string rollup can be done in Athena

Like

```
ID    NAME    ROW_TYPE          TIME
1     A        Insert, Update   1:00, 1:05
2     B        Insert           1:06
3     C        Insert           1:07
```

Any better or proper suggestions ? Also I have no idea what this is called. I apologize for my lack of terminology (it has made it hard to google and find the answer myself)  I'm learning !

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more and give more examples. In provided example count distinct with grouping by id seems to work fine.

Comment: Many ways we can achieve this. Using rank function subquery, group by etc. Rank ex: select * from (select row_number() over (partition by ID order by TIME desc) as rnk from <table_name>)a  where a.rnk = 1